# Chrome issue with 301 redirect and SSL

Tags: google-chrome, redirect, ssl

I am currently experiencing an issue that only occurs in Chrome. If I use https://example.com it won't load in chrome and it will complain with the following message:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> The webpage at https://example.com/ might be temporarily down or it may
>   have moved permanently to a new web address.
>   ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TRUNCATED

It works fine in any other browser but Chrome.

If I only use `http` then it works fine.

I read somewhere that if I use 302 redirect the problem is solved. So I asked the team to test it and it actually solved the issue, however, we are avoiding using 302 and we need to stick with 301.

Comment: There is no general problem with Chrome and 301. Thus this is not a problem which can be reproduced with just the information you provide. Instead it must be a problem with your site or with your network. If you would provide the URL in question one might have a closer look if this is a site specific problem.

Comment: ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TRUNCATED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think it's anything to do with 301 or 302. Think it's because you are setting them up differently- in that you are not closing the 301 request properly.

See here:  https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/chrome/2tttvx4VCDQ/kUIE1FXxve0J

This works:

```
"HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\n" + "Location: https://www.example.com" + http.req.url.path_and_query.http_url_safe + "\r\n\r\n"
```

This doesn't:

```
"HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\n" + "Location: https://www.example.com" + http.req.url.path_and_query.http_url_safe + "\r\n"
```